# atualizar contador de caracteres de um input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Eu tenho uma página na qual se pode adicionar campos em que, carregando em "criar novo campo" abre um `modal` com um `input` com um contador de caracteres e dois botões, podendo adicionar quantos campos quiser. 
No entanto, quando crio o primeiro, o valor que fica desse contador(vamos supor que fica 14 car. restantes), é o valor que aparece quando crio um novo campo e abre um novo modal. Apenas atualiza, isto é, volta para o número máximo de caracteres permitido (20) quando carrego no input para escrever.

Eu criei estes elements para fazer o update:

```
  element.focus(updateCounter).change(updateCounter);
  element.keyup(updateCounter).change(updateCounter);
```

Há algo do género que possa fazer para atualizar assim que o `modal` abra, antes de fazer `focus` no `input`?

Comment: Está pouco claro, posta o código dos inputs.

Comment: como você está abrindo o modal? posta o código